# SwiftUI / Core Data - Involuntary navigation between list view and detailed view when updating detailed view

Tags: core-data, swiftui-list, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui

I am using a TabView/NavigationView & NavigationLink to programmatically navigate from a list view to detailed view and when I update the boolean property 'pinned' to true & save the core data entity in the detailed view, I am getting the following unfortunate side effects:

1. an involuntary navigation back to the list view and then again back to the detailed view **or**
2. an involuntary navigation to another copy of the same detailed view and then back to the list view.

I have prepared a small [Xcode project with the complete sample code](https://github.com/abildgaard/swiftui-navigationlink-issue)

In the list view I use @FetchRequest to query the list and sort on the following:

```
    @FetchRequest(entity: Task.entity(),sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(key: "pinned", ascending: false),
                                                          NSSortDescriptor(key: "created", ascending: true),
                                                          NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)])
```

In the list view I use the following:

```
List() {
   ForEach(tasks, id: \.self) { task in
       NavigationLink(destination: DetailsView(task: task), tag: task.id!.uuidString, selection: self.$selectionId) {
         HStack() {
            ...
         }
      }
}
```

.

(1) If I omit the 'NSSortDescriptor(key: "pinned" ...)' I don't see the behavior.

(2) If I omit the 'tag:' and the 'selection:' parameters in the NavigationLink() I don't see the behavior. But I need to be able to trigger the navigation link programmatically when I create a new Task entity.

(3) It seems never to happen when I have a single entity in the list or changing the value of the 'pinned' boolean property in the first entity in the list.

(4) I get the warning:

> [TableView] Warning once only: UITableView was told to layout its visible cells and other contents without being in the view hierarchy (the table view or one of its superviews has not been added to a window)...

The parent view to the list view (TasksListView) contains a TabView:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            NavigationView {
                TasksListView()
            }
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "tray.full")
                    .font(.title)
                Text("Master")
            }
            NavigationView {
                EmptyView()
            }
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
                    .font(.title)
                Text("Search")
            }
        }  
    }
}

struct TasksListView: View {
    
    // NSManagedObjectContext
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var viewContext

    // Results of fetch request for tasks:
    @FetchRequest(entity: Task.entity(),sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(key: "pinned", ascending: false),
                                                          NSSortDescriptor(key: "created", ascending: true),
                                                          NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)])
    var tasks: FetchedResults<Task>
    
    // when we create a new task and navigate to it programitically
    @State var selectionId : String?
    @State var newTask : Task?


    var body: some View {
        
        List() {
            ForEach(tasks, id: \.self) { task in
                NavigationLink(destination: DetailsView(task: task), tag: task.id!.uuidString, selection: self.$selectionId) {
                    HStack() {
                        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                            Text("\(task.name ?? "unknown")")
                                .font(Font.headline.weight(.light))
                                .padding(.bottom,5)
                            Text("Created:\t\(task.created ?? Date(), formatter: Self.dateFormatter)")
                                .font(Font.subheadline.weight(.light))
                                .padding(.bottom,5)
                            if task.due != nil {
                                Text("Due:\t\t\(task.due!, formatter: Self.dateFormatter)")
                                    .font(Font.subheadline.weight(.light))
                                    .padding(.bottom,5)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle(Text("Tasks"),displayMode: .inline)
        .navigationBarItems(trailing: rightButton)
    }
    
    
    var rightButton: some View {
        Image(systemName: "plus.circle")
            .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.systemBlue))
            .font(.title)
            .contentShape(Rectangle())
            .onTapGesture {
                // create a new task and navigate to it's detailed view to add values
                Task.create(in: self.viewContext) { (task, success, error) in
                    if success {
                        self.newTask = task
                        self.selectionId = task!.id!.uuidString
                    }
                }
                
        }
    }
}

struct DetailsView: View {
    
    // NSManagedObjectContext
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var viewContext
        
    @ObservedObject var task : Task
    
    @State var name : String = ""
    @State var dueDate : Date = Date()
    @State var hasDueDate : Bool = false
    @State var isPinned : Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        
        List() {
            
            Section() {
                Toggle(isOn: self.$isPinned) {
                    Text("Pinned")
                }
            }
            
            Section() {
                TextField("Name", text: self.$name)
                    .font(Font.headline.weight(.light))
                Text("\(task.id?.uuidString ?? "unknown")")
                    .font(Font.headline.weight(.light))
            }
            
            Section() {
                HStack() {
                    Text("Created")
                    Spacer()
                    Text("\(task.created ?? Date(), formatter: Self.dateFormatter)")
                        .font(Font.subheadline.weight(.light))
                }
            
                Toggle(isOn: self.$hasDueDate) {
                    Text("Set Due Date")
                }
                
                if self.hasDueDate {
                    DatePicker("Due Date", selection: self.$dueDate, in: Date()... , displayedComponents: [.hourAndMinute, .date])
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle(Text("Task Details"),displayMode: .inline)
        .navigationBarItems(trailing: rightButton)
        .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
        .onAppear() {
            if self.task.pinned {
                self.isPinned = true
            }
            if self.task.name != nil {
                self.name = self.task.name!
            }
            if self.task.due != nil {
                self.dueDate = self.task.due!
                self.hasDueDate = true
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    // save button
    
    var rightButton: some View {
        
        Button("Save") {

            // save values in task & save:
            self.task.pinned = self.isPinned
            if self.hasDueDate  {
                self.task.due = self.dueDate
            }
            
            if self.name.count > 0 {
                self.task.name = self.name
            }
            
            Task.save(in: self.viewContext) { (success, error) in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    if success {
                        print("Task saved")
                    }
                    else {
                        print("****** Error: Task can't be saved, error = \(error!.localizedDescription)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .contentShape(Rectangle())        
    }
    
    
}

extension Task {
    
    static func save(in managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext, completion: @escaping (Bool, NSError?) -> Void ) {
        managedObjectContext.performAndWait() {
            do {
                try managedObjectContext.save()
                completion(true, nil)
            } catch {
                let nserror = error as NSError
                print("****** Error: Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
                completion(false, nserror)
            }
        }
     }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be creating your tab view in a different way than me. Those extra navigation views made cause an issue.

Not sure if it will help or not but I do it like that:

```
struct ContentView: View {
var body: some View {
    TabView {
         TasksListView()
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "tray.full")
                    .font(.title)
                Text("Master")
        }

            EmptyView()
              .tabItem {
                  Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
                      .font(.title)
                  Text("Search")
        }
    }  
}
```

}

Comment: sadly not. I can add the NavigationView() into the TasksListView() and other views but the issue remains. Thx for the suggestion!

Comment: I am seeing precisely the same behavior if I use Xcode's Master-Detail project template and make a few additions:
 (1) added BOOL property 'pinned' to the core data Entity
 (2) added Toggle view to the DetailView
 (3) added save button to the DetailedView
 (4) changed the  NSSortDescriptor to use pinned property
It gives me the same unfortunate side effects when I set & save the pinned value to true

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in `iOS 13`.

It has been fixed since `iOS 14.0 beta 3`.

You will find a similar question here (the accepted answer provides a workaround):

[Issue when rearranging List item in detail view using SwiftUI Navigation View and Sorted FetchRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61005551/issue-when-rearranging-list-item-in-detail-view-using-swiftui-navigation-view-an/61065434#61065434)

Comment: Xcode version 12.0 beta 4 the behavior above has been fixed but still has some issues: When I update my boolean/save & navigate back to the list view using the back button, the app inadvertently navigates back to the detailed view.  NOTE: I am testing this behavior using Xcode's generated Master-Detail with Core Data project example and adding boolean property to the Event entity (as well as id: UUID) and in this case I am not using the (..., tag: selection:) parameters for the NavigationLink. If I add these parameters and trigger the link programmatically I get the same behavior.

Comment: @abildgaard I did not test the GitHub project linked in your question on iOS 14.0 because it was crashing. Xcode 12 beta 4 does not seem to offer the Master Detail template any longer. So I created a new project with the latest XCode11 using the Master Detail template and made the changes you describe in your comment and could reproduce your issue, so it seems it is still not resolved when using DoubleColumnNavigationViewStyle(). You might want to provide Feedback to Apple. I was able to solve/workaround the misbehaviour by adding .id(UUID()) to List in MasterView. Does this work for you?

Comment: [@Lobo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10060753/lobo)  I did report to Apple. Could you provide more details in the workaround - do you mean the keypath in the ForEach? I am using "List { ForEach(events, id: \.id) { event in ...}}" as my Event.id is of type UUID.

Comment: @abildgaard I mean adding an .id modifier to the List, i.e. List { ForEach(events, id: \.id) { event in ...}}.id(UUID())
This will force the creation of a brand new list every time the body property is invoked and thus eliminate the misbehaviour.