# Saving Item in CoreData Initiates Navigation

Tags: core-data, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

In my ContentView I have a `FetchRequest<Project>`. I navigate to `ProjectView` using a `NavigationLink`. From `ProjectView` I navigate to `AddItemView` using another `NavigationLink`. In `AddItemView` when I add an `Item` to the `Project` and call `container.viewContext.save()` the `AddItemView` automatically dismisses back to the `ContentView`.
My guess is that saving to `CoreData` updates the `FetchRequest<Project>` list which in turn updates the views, but I am not sure.

How can I save a new `Item` to the `Project` in `CoreData` and only navigate back to `ProjectView` and not `ContentView`?

To reproduce:

1. Create new Single View App and check Core Data and Host in CloudKit
2. In the .xcdatamodel delete the default Entity and replace it with an Entity called Project which has attributes date: Date and title: String and an Entity called Item which has an attribute name: String. Give the Project a relationship called items (to type Item) and choose “to many” on the right. Give the Item a relationship called project that is the inverse of items.
3. Replace the code in Persistence.swift with this:

```swift
// Persistence.swift
import CoreData

struct PersistenceController {
    static let shared = PersistenceController()

    let container: NSPersistentCloudKitContainer

    init(inMemory: Bool = false) {
        container = NSPersistentCloudKitContainer(name: "CoreDataBug")
        if inMemory {
            container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first!.url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/dev/null")
        }
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.

                /*
                Typical reasons for an error here include:
                * The parent directory does not exist, cannot be created, or disallows writing.
                * The persistent store is not accessible, due to permissions or data protection when the device is locked.
                * The device is out of space.
                * The store could not be migrated to the current model version.
                Check the error message to determine what the actual problem was.
                */
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
    }
}
```

4. Copy ContentView

```swift
//  ContentView.swift

import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc

    let projects: FetchRequest<Project>

    init() {
        projects = FetchRequest<Project>(entity: Project.entity(), sortDescriptors: [
            NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Project.date, ascending: false)
        ])
    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(projects.wrappedValue) { project in
                    NavigationLink(destination: ProjectView(project: project)) {
                        Text(project.title ?? "Title")
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Projects")
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: ToolbarItemPlacement.navigationBarTrailing) {
                    Button {
                        withAnimation {
                            let project = Project(context: moc)
                            let now = Date()
                            project.date = now
                            project.title = now.description
                            try? moc.save()
                        }
                    } label: {
                        Label("Add Project", systemImage: "plus")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

5. Create ProjectView.swift and copy this:

```swift
// ProjectView.swift
import SwiftUI

struct ProjectView: View {

    @ObservedObject var project: Project

    var items: [Item] {
        project.items?.allObjects as? [Item] ?? []
    }

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(items) { item in
                Text(item.name ?? "")
            }
        }
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: ToolbarItemPlacement.navigationBarTrailing) {
                NavigationLink(destination: AddItemView(project: project)) {
                    Label("Add Item", systemImage: "plus")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

6. Create AddItemView.swift and copy this:

```swift
import SwiftUI

// AddItemView.swift

import SwiftUI

struct AddItemView: View {

    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc

    let project: Project

    @State private var selectedName: String =  ""

    var body: some View {
        TextField("Type name here", text: $selectedName)
            .navigationTitle("Add Item")
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button("Add") {
                let ingestion = Item(context: moc)
                ingestion.project = project
                ingestion.name = selectedName
                try? moc.save()
                presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            })
    }
}
```

7. Run the app. Click the plus on the top right. Click the project that just slid in. In the `ProjectView` click the plus on the top right again. Type a name in the `TextField` and click add on the top right. When the `AddItemView` is dismissed it probably went back to `ContentView`. If not add another item to the project.

Comment: Please include some of your code; particularly the content view, how you build the navigation link, and what controls how the navigation link is presented

Comment: This looks like the same behaviour described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61005551/issue-when-rearranging-list-item-in-detail-view-using-swiftui-navigation-view-an?rq=1

Comment: I can't reproduce the bug in the other question on iOS 14.5 as it seems to be a bug that was part of iOS 13.4

Comment: Excellent job at updating the question, I can now reproduce your bug perfectly... but can't fix it. I added a selection binding to your navigation items but that just meant that on hitting add the list went back to the start and then pushed the project again, it never did a single pop like it should.